# Quando eu coloco a classe na primeira <section> ele funciona , mas na segunda <section> (com a mesma classe) o efeito não funciona - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

- Quando eu clica-se em alguma dessas latas o background ia mudar de cor e a lata principal também :

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Só que o background da segunda section não esta mudando de cor(E ela tem a mesma `class`) :
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs : eu quero que a classe de cima fica com a mesma cor da classe debaixo.

- HTML

```html
<!--Primeira <section>  -->
<section class="corDeFundo">
    
</section>
<!-- Segunda <Section>-->
<section class="corDeFundo">
    <div class="produto" id="produto">
        <h1>produto</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

- JavaScript(Completo)

  ```
  const corDeFundo = document.querySelector(".corDeFundo")
    const latasDeRefri = document.querySelectorAll(".latasDeRefri li")
    const pepsiPrincipal = document.querySelector(".pepsi")

    latasDeRefri[0].addEventListener("click",()=>{
        pepsiPrincipal.src = "imagem/pepsi1.png"
        corDeFundo.style.background = "#004999"
        corDeFundo.style.transition = "0.5s"
    })
    latasDeRefri[1].addEventListener("click",()=>{
        pepsiPrincipal.src = "imagem/pepsi2.png"
        corDeFundo.style.background = "#ED0223"
        corDeFundo.style.transition = "0.5s"
    })
    latasDeRefri[2].addEventListener("click",()=>{
        pepsiPrincipal.src = "imagem/pepsi3.png"
        corDeFundo.style.background = "#191C1E"
        corDeFundo.style.transition = "0.5s"
    })
  ```

Comment: usa a ferramenta do navegador pra investigar qual elemeto está definindo o background, não seria uma div dentro dela, como a div com id "produto"?

Comment: Olhei aqui , e o que está definindo a cor é a class="corDeFundo",  só que o efeito só é aplicado na primeira <section class="corDeFundo">, e o efeito tem que ser aplicado na segunda <section> com a mesma classe.

Comment: Coloquei o html completo , da uma olhada agora

Comment: `latasDeRefri[0]` isso aqui, assim como os outros, usando o índice zero vai alterar só o primeiro item

Comment: latasDeRefri[0] vai pegar a primeira lata(Azul) e colocar como principal e alterar a cor de fundo para azul , o que está errado ?

Comment: se tiver apenas esses elementos não tem problema. Agora quanto ao background, está usando o seletor `document.querySelector` que traz 1 elemento, ou seja, só vai alterar o primeiro elemento com a class "corDeFundo", deveria usar `querySelectorAll` e alterar todos

Comment: realmente é isso mesmo , MUITO OBRIGADO !!! , mas como eu pego todos os items do array ? (Eu fiz usando o FOR , mas se tiver outra maneira comenta na resposta da pergunta) , obs: Se puder dar like na pergunta eu agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo o ultimo comentário, precisa então usar o `querySelectorAll`, que retornar um array de objetos.

Precisa iterar sobre cada elemento, pode ser feito com `for`, `foreach`, etc. Eu costumo usar assim, é simples e claro:

```
const corDeFundo = document.querySelectorAll(".corDeFundo")

...

corDeFundo.forEach((elemento) => {
    elemento.style.background = "#191C1E"
    elemento.style.transition = "0.5s"
});
```

Ou assim também:

```
for (const elemento of corDeFundo) {
  elemento.style.background = "#191C1E"
  elemento.style.transition = "0.5s"
}
```

Porém esse `for` não é compatível com algumas versões mais antigas de navegador, convém confirmar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Muito Obrigado Ricardo :)