# querySelectorAll não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando puxar umas tags do html para rodar o meu script, porém eu usei o querySelector e não funcionou, abaixo o código. Eu tenho vários spans desse, gostaria de saber como resolvo, uso o console e não aparece

```
<span class="buy">R$5,00<a class="select" data-ordem="3" href="#">Comprar</a></span>
```

```
const select = document.querySelectorAll(".select");
console.log(select);
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` retorna uma array de objetos, precisa interar usado for ou foreach por exemplo

Comment: veja essa outra pergunta, respondi algo bem parecido: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/490925/57220

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver o problema, era um erro no arquivo tbm que fez não rodar tudo certo, mas me ajudou bastante